# Block all internet traffic on a rooted device

Tags: root-access, system

I want to block completely and **forever**(even after factory-restoring the device) all the internet connectivity(WiFi, 3G and 4G) on a rooted device.

Comment: Open the case and destroy the antenna

Comment: Antenna-way seems quite reasonable for you :) Even no need to be rooted .

Comment: I can break the WiFi antenna, but if I break the celular antenna(to "block" 3G and 4G) I won't be able to make calls anymore ; )...